# How to setup multiple PHP-FPM masters on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, unix-socket

I've been following [this tutorial](https://ma.ttias.be/a-better-way-to-run-php-fpm/) to setup multiple PHP-FPM masters for each of my wordpress multisite installations so that they can run independently from each other concerning APC cache and other options.

After following the directions to the letter, each new php5-fpm init.d script won't actually initialize or do anything.
Also `/var/run/php5-fpm-master2.pid` and `php5-fpm-master2.sock` aren't being created. Considering I've followed directions, I'm assuming either his `distro/package` versions are different or I'm missing something between the lines.

Anyone willing to share how to properly setup multiple PHP-FPM masters (standard php5-fpm from apt-get) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3):

I’m not using Ubuntu but Debian Jessie, which should be the same here.

First of all, go to `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d`.

There you have to create your pools, e. g. one with the filename `www1.conf`:

```
[www1]
user = www1
group = www1

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-www1.sock
listen.owner = www1
listen.group = www1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 100
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;
chdir = /
```

Create a second one, e. g. with the filename `www2.conf`:

```
[www2]
user = www2
group = www2

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-www2.sock
listen.owner = www2
listen.group = www2
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 100
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;
chdir = /
```

Now go to `/etc/php5/fpm` and remove the `php-fpm.conf` in it (backup in a separate directory would be useful). Now create the file `php-fpm-www1.conf` with the following content:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm-www1.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm-www1.log
syslog.ident = php-fpm-www1
log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www1.conf
```

Similar to that, create the file `php-fpm-www2.conf`:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm-www2.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm-www2.log
syslog.ident = php-fpm-www2
log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www2.conf
```

That’s the full configuration you need. The most important part is a proper init script. On Debian, I just copied the default `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm`.

File `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm-www1`:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php5-fpm-www1
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
# Short-Description: starts php5-fpm-www1
# Description:       Starts The PHP FastCGI Process Manager Daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Ondrej Sury <ondrej@debian.org>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php5-fpm-www1
BIN=php5-fpm
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$BIN
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-www1.conf"
CONF_PIDFILE=$(sed -n 's/^pid\s*=\s*//p' /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-www1.conf)
PIDFILE=${CONF_PIDFILE:-/run/php5-fpm-www1.pid}
TIMEOUT=30
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Don't run if we are running upstart
if init_is_upstart; then
    exit 1
fi

#
# Function to check the correctness of the config file
#
do_check()
{
    /usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf || return 1
    return 0
}

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS 2>/dev/null \
        || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=QUIT/$TIMEOUT/TERM/5/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/TERM/5/KILL/5 --name $NAME --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR2 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_check $VERBOSE
    case "$?" in
        0)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
        1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
    stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    check)
        do_check yes
    ;;
    reload|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_reload
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    reopen-logs)
    log_daemon_msg "Reopening $DESC logs" $NAME
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --oknodo --quiet \
        --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
    then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

:
```

The changes from the default init script were:

The commentary:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php5-fpm-www1
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
# Short-Description: starts php5-fpm-www1
# Description:       Starts The PHP FastCGI Process Manager Daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

Here you have to change line 2 and 7 to your script name.

Configuration:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php5-fpm-www1
BIN=php5-fpm
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$BIN
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-www1.conf"
CONF_PIDFILE=$(sed -n 's/^pid\s*=\s*//p' /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-www1.conf)
PIDFILE=${CONF_PIDFILE:-/run/php5-fpm-www1.pid}
TIMEOUT=30
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
```

Change the `NAME` variable to your script name and add the `BIN` variable with the name of your bin file. Additionally edit the `DAEMON` to match `$BIN` instead of `$NAME`. `DAEMON:ARGS`, `CONF_PIDFILE` and `PIDFILE` have to be edited to match your configurations in `/etc/php5/fpm`.

Now the script should already start the specific PHP5-FPM master.

My problem was that a `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm-www1 stop` did also stop the master of `www2`.

To fix that you have to edit the `do_stop()` function in the init script:

```
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=QUIT/$TIMEOUT/TERM/5/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/TERM/5/KILL/5 --name $NAME --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}
```

Here I had to add the `--name $NAME` to the second `start-stop-daemon` command in line 17.

The same thing you have to to with your `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm-www2` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php5-fpm-www2
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
# Short-Description: starts php5-fpm-www2
# Description:       Starts The PHP FastCGI Process Manager Daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Ondrej Sury <ondrej@debian.org>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php5-fpm-www2
BIN=php5-fpm
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$BIN
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-www2.conf"
CONF_PIDFILE=$(sed -n 's/^pid\s*=\s*//p' /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm-www2.conf)
PIDFILE=${CONF_PIDFILE:-/run/php5-fpm-www2.pid}
TIMEOUT=30
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Don't run if we are running upstart
if init_is_upstart; then
    exit 1
fi

#
# Function to check the correctness of the config file
#
do_check()
{
    /usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf || return 1
    return 0
}

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS 2>/dev/null \
        || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=QUIT/$TIMEOUT/TERM/5/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/TERM/5/KILL/5 --name $NAME --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR2 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_check $VERBOSE
    case "$?" in
        0)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
        1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
    stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    check)
        do_check yes
    ;;
    reload|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_reload
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    reopen-logs)
    log_daemon_msg "Reopening $DESC logs" $NAME
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --oknodo --quiet \
        --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
    then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

:
```

Please keep in mind to keep your init script up-to-date in order a regular update of `php5-fpm` changes something.

Comment: why are you specifying different users?

Comment: Because otherwise it doesn’t really make any sense to have multiple masters. Multiple masters are usually used to divide code of different users from each other. If one gets hijacked, the other user is not directly hijacked, too.

Comment: they're also useful in a single user environment if you need to restart php without downtime